# JSON request using Postman

Tags: json, postman

I am sending a raw Json requet using postman to an API service which feeds it to another web service and finally a database. I want to attach a file to the raw Json request.

I am attaching below the current request I am sending. Is it the right way? The first name and other information is going through but the attachment is not. Any suggestions?

```
{
  "Prefix": "",
  "FirstName": "test-resume-dlyon",
  "LastName": "test-dlyon-resume",
  "AddressLine1": "test2",
  "AddressLine2": "",
  "City": "Invalid Zipcode",
  "State": "GA",
  "Zip": "99999",
  "Phone": "9999999999",
  "Email": "testresumedlyon@gmail.com",
  "Source": "V",
  "WritingNumber": "",
  "AgeVerified": true,
  "AdditionalSource": "",
  "EnableInternetSource": true,
  "InternetSource": "",
  "ExternalResult": "",
  "PartnerID": "",
  "SubscriberID": "15584",
  "Languages": [
    "English",
    "Spanish"
  ],
  "fileName": "resume",
  "fileExtension": "docx",
  "fileData": "UELDMxE76DDKlagmIF5caEVHmJYFv2qF6DpmMSkVPxVdtJxgRYV"
}
```

Comment: Please format your code as such. See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks

Comment: If this is exact, there’s a missing close quote on fileData

Comment: the previous one was not the exact one there was a quote present on the fileData

Comment: Is this the correct format to attach a file to a JSON raw request in Postman??

Answer (score 0):

There is no "correct" format to attach a file to a JSON.

JSON is not multipart/form-data (which is designed to include files).

JSON is a text-based data format with a variety of data types (such as strings, arrays, and booleans) but nothing specific for files.

This means that to attach a file, you have to get creative.

For example, you *could* encode a file in text format (e.g. using [base64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64)), but it wouldn't be very efficient, and any Word document would result in you getting a **much** longer string than `"UELDMxE76DDKlagmIF5caEVHmJYFv2qF6DpmMSkVPxVdtJxgRYV"`.

Of course, the method you use to encode the file has to be the method that *whatever is reading the JSON* expects you to use. Since there is no standard for this, and you have said nothing about the system which is consuming the JSON you are sending, we have no idea what that method is.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I'd recommend reading the [postman API docs](https://learning.getpostman.com/docs/postman/launching_postman/installation_and_updates/). They have some extremely useful information on there for using the API. Two particular articles that might of interest here are these:

Looking at it and running it through a validator like [this one](http://json.parser.online.fr/) shows that there are no syntax errors so it must be to do with the JSON parameters the API is expecting.

---

**Here's something you can try:**

In postman, set method type to **POST**.

Then select **Body** -> **form-data** -> Enter your parameter name (file according to your code)

and on right side next to value column, there will be dropdown **"text, file"**, select **File**. choose your image file and post it.

For rest of *"text"* based parameters, you can post it like normally you do with Postman. Just enter parameter name and select **"text"** from that right side dropdown menu and enter any value for it, hit send button. Your controller method should get called.

Comment: @halfer I will absolutely add "fluff". It's my answer. Not yours. You might also noticed an upvoted comment on there is **"Be careful not to remove information which is important to tailoring answers to the asker's experience level"** The user is new. I have every right to make them feel welcome